# data analysis query

Tags: time-series

The hydrophone data is in analog-to-digital converter units. The 64000 sps data is 24 bits and the 375 ksps data is 16 bit.

The volts per bit conversion factor for the 24-bit channels is 1.49365435131571E-07 and for the 16-bit it is 0.0000625.

My query is how do I make sure looking at my time series for the two channels and be sure the conversion factor was taken into account or how do i figure out the units of the hydrop

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the actual sound pressure in Pascal, by far the best method is to use a calibrator or recording a calibration signal with a known pressure amplitude.

You can potentially work through the signal chain using the data sheets (hydrophone sensitivity, pre-amp gai, D/A configuration, D/A gain) but that's very error prone typically not very precise.

Comment: I have the calibration of the hydrophone done and its sensitivity is -163.77 dBV/uPa.